# JLS: Modifiers before package keyword

Tags: java, eclipse, package, modifier, jls

I just discovered that several modifiers can be written before the package declaration in a class. It seems all visibility modifiers are allowed as well as field modifiers and all of them multiple times. A declaration might look like this:

```
public public final static private private static protected
volatile synchronized strictfp strictfp static final package de.lfnn.test;
```

**What could it possibly mean??**

For me on first sight it looks like it is syntactic gibberish. Some hole in the JLS that compiles but does not affect the compiler in any way.

(and yes, I have searched the JLS and the net ;-))

UPDATE: As pointed out by @assylias the JLS does not allow this construct. I've tried to compile it with javac and it fails. Nevertheless the eclipse compiler allows it.

Comment: Where have you seen that?

Comment: Are you asking why that *exact* example might be useful? Or are you asking why this is allowed by the compiler?

Comment: @assylias I've written the example myself, using Eclipse 3.7.1 and Java SDK 1.7.0_40

Comment: @Duncan I'm asking what effect those modifiers have. Or if it is just some language anomaly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where you read that but the syntax you propose is invalid. A [package declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4) must follow the syntax:

> `PackageDeclaration:`
>   `Annotations`<sub>`opt`</sub> `package PackageName ;`

So you could have an annotation before the `package` keyword, but that's it. For example, `public package a.b.c;` is not a valid statement and generates the following compilation error with javac (in jdk 8):

```
Test1.java:5: error: class, interface, or enum expected
public package a.b.c;
1 error
```

Note: It seems that `public package a.b.c;` compiles with some compilers. That looks like a bug since it does not match the language specification.

Comment: It does appear to compile though. At least Eclipse will compile it happily. So perhaps a bug in the compiler then to allow this?

Comment: @Duncan javac (in jdk 8) doesn't.

Comment: Confirmed that with JDK 7 using Netbeans 7.4 beta it also compiles, however Netbeans underlines it as syntax error.

Comment: @assylias Looks like a bug in the Eclipse compiler. I can confirm a normal Java 7 compilation will fail from the command line.

Comment: I can confirm javac fails on the command line but the eclipse compiler accepts it.

Comment: There's a bug filed against Eclipse about it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411103